# Select all hyperlink with id that is visible

Tags: jquery, hidden, each

I have lot of this hyperlink in my page. Some of them are visible and some are hidden.

```
 <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="close_car2">&#215;</a>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="close_car3">&#215;</a>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal" id="close_car4" style="display:none;" >&#215;</a>
```

So right now i want to iterate through all the visible hyperlink that the id start with "close_" and get the index, assign unique text to the hyperlink.

This is sample of my code but it is not working.

```
$("a[id^='close_']").is(':visible').each(function (index) {
        if(index=='0')
        {
            $(this).text('test');
        }
    });
```

How to solve this? Thanks

Comment: You're using `each` but then checking `index==0`. Couldn't you just select the first element with `$(...)[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("a[id^='close_']:visible").each(function (index) {
```

From the docs on "is()":

> Unlike other filtering methods, .is() does not create a new jQuery
>   object. Instead, it allows you to test the contents of a jQuery object
>   without modification.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work

```
$('a[id*="close_"]').each(function(i){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        if(i == 0){
            $(this).text('Link One');
        }
        if(i == 1){
             $(this).text('Link Two');
        }        
    }    
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xC4Fp/1

Comment: If the first two links are not `visible` then there will be no alerts.

Comment: @d3v3us. You're right.  But the OP wants to *get the index, assign unique text to the hyperlink*.  So he needs to know order here if he wants to assign something unique.  Or he has to show more code for a more elegant fix.  But, yes, as it is... it works with the code provided.